# Move row on spreadsheet using scripts and have a button on the sheet to activate it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet where essentially I would like all actioned lines to be moved to an archive tab once actioned. As a lot of people will be using it I would ideally like a button at the top which would activate the script? I've tried a few things I've found on the web but nothing seems to fit in with what I need exactly.

I'm not sure whether it would work best to have a tickbox in column J which would be the ones to move or if having a "Complete" status in Column F would work better?

I've attached a dummy document to work on, any help would be greatly appreciated!!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CoBzUxme8Rrwy6XfFy1m0BzwhWtqR-KyGDMGQq2F478/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT - have now updated with a script however it doesn't seem to work for all users, is there some way to change the trigger from upon an edit to pushing a button on the spreadsheet or something like that?

Error message when trying to run script - think this may be because it is triggered on edit?

[image]

Comment: what  have you tried so far?  Any links that feel like they're close, but not quite what you need? There are a ton of answers to this question here on Stack as well as the internet generally.

Comment: Hi, I tried one which i have now added to the spreadsheet, the issues I have are this one only seems to respond when i action the tick boxes, other people have tried but no luck. I also think that due to the number of people using it it would be better to have a button to click to start the script rather than on every edit. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Installable Trigger

You can create an onEdit Installable Trigger that will check if the value of column F is changed to "Completed". onEdit Trigger will automatically execute your script when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.

Try this:

*Rename the function **onEdit(e)** from previous answer with **moveRow(e)** to avoid double execution of triggers.*

```
function moveRow(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var value = e.value;
  if(range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Log Sheet" && row > 1 && column == 6 && value == "Completed"){
    var archiveSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE DO NOT USE");
    var lastRow = archiveSheet.getLastRow();
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).moveTo(archiveSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

How to create Installable Trigger?

> 1. Open your Apps Script project.
> 2. At the left, click Triggers alarm.
> 3. At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
> 4. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.
> 5. Click Save.

Your trigger setup should look like this:

[image: Trigger]

**Note:** To make this script works, the user must update the value of a cell to "Completed" in the **Status** column of the Log Sheet. This was also tested using multiple users editing the Sheet. Also, Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger, it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has edit access), but it runs as your account.

---

### Option 2: Button

In your script editor, paste the following code.

```
function moveRows(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log Sheet");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 10);
  var data = range.getValues();
  var archiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE DO NOT USE");
  
  for(var i = data.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(data[i][5] == "Completed"){
      var lastRow = archiveSheet.getLastRow();
      sheet.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 10).moveTo(archiveSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
      sheet.deleteRow(i+2);
    };
  };
```

Then assign script to a button in Google Sheets:

> 1. Add a button via the Insert > Drawing menu > Add the desired button shape and save.
> 2. Right click to the button > click the 3 vertical dot > click Assign Script > type `moveRows`.
> 3. Click the button to execute the script

---

### Output:

**Example:**

### Before changing Status to Completed:

**Log Sheet:**

[image]

**Archive:**

[image]

### After changing Status to Completed:

**Log Sheet:**

[image]

**Archive:**

[image]

### References:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Hi, this is great and works ok so thank you!! however when i try getting someone else to edit the sheet the rows don't move at all? They have edit access to the sheet so not sure why it wouldn't work. I think maybe using a button that anyone can click to activate the script may work better but not sure how to add that in and what the trigger would need to be renamed to, thanks for your help!

Comment: @DanRob95 - Could you go to the Execution tab and take a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Hi! When i try to run the script it comes up with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ Code.gs:2 (Screenshot attached to original post). But I think this is due to it being an "OnEdit" script so may not be too helpful. it seems to work perfectly for me but is hit and miss for others using the script.

Comment: @DanRob95 - Executions Tab is located on the left side of your script and above the project settings. There you can see every logs of your script.

Comment: @DanRob95 - I updated my answer above and added option for Installable Trigger and manual execution via button. In my previous answer, the script I is intended for onEdit Trigger events. Running the script in the script editor will cause the TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' since there is no event object passed by the Sheets. Kindly let me know if my script works.

Comment: J, this is fabulous!! thank you so much, it's exactly what I was trying to do, and thanks for tip about looking at executions, didn't realise that bit existed! Thanks again!